# Transform xml file into an other xml format

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have one question regarding transforming xml files.
I have an xml file (xml1) , that has this structure :

```
<Info>
  <cars>
   <car>
       <id>1</id>
       <brand>Pegeout</brand>
    </car>
    <car>
       <id>2</id>
       <brand>Volkwagen</brand>
    </car>
  </cars>
  <distances>
    <distance>
      <id_car>1</id_car>
      <distance_km>111</distance_km>
    </distance>
    <distance>
        <id_car>1</id_car>
        <distance_km>23</distance_km>
    </distance>
  </distances>
</Info>
```

I undestand that I can transform one xml to an other using xslt .How can I generate an xsl stylesheet ? Exist a designer in C#?

Can someone tell me how can I transform this xml file  format to this format (xml2 )  using XSL stylesheets in C#:

```
<Info>
  <cars>
   <car>
       <id>1</id>
       <brand>Pegeout</brand>
       <distance>
          <distance_km>111</distance_km>
          <distance_km>23</distance_km>
       </distance>
   </car>
    <car>
       <id>2</id>
       <brand>Volkwagen</brand>
    </car>
  </cars>
</Info>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read the [guide to asking a good question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and show [what you have tried](http://whatyouhavetried.com).

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Transformations might help.  Sadly, it looks like there might not be anythign C#-native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a key to reference the elements by id:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="id" match="distance" use="id_car"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="car">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="ref-dist" select="key('id', id)/distance_km"/>
    <xsl:if test="$ref-dist">
      <distance>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$ref-dist"/>
      </distance>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Info/distances"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```